# how come google contacts on web have no last name, only name

Tags: contacts, sync, google-contacts

On my android the contacts have first and last name, where in contacts.google.com there's only a name field?

I'm asking because whenever I change my name there I see no effect on my android device, and thought this might be related.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if sync is activated on your phone. It may be because of syncing problem that the change is not reflected.

Comment: it is activated